# GLubyte vs GLshort for Indices

Tags: opengl, indices

Looking through documentation for vertex arrays in OpenGL, two of the most common memory types used for indices I found were GLubyte (GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE) and GLshort (GL_SHORT).
I was wondering if there was any actual difference between using the two for indices

Thanks,
Dragonwrenn

Comment: Are you sure that a short takes less memory than a byte? I do not know OpenGL, but usually it is the other way around (a short being maybe two bytes).

Comment: @Thilo: In all honesty, they will probably take the same amount of memory because the driver has to convert 8-bit indices to 16-bit for most desktop GPUs. The OpenGL API makes it appear that 8-bit indices are a viable option, but behind the scenes the hardware does not like them. OpenGL does this sort of stuff a lot, sadly... OpenGL drivers are a lot of smoke and mirrors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` is OK for models which have at most 256 vertices - that's really not many.

`GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT`, taking 2 bytes, would limit you to 65536 vertices - still that's kind of few.

I'd say the most common variant is `GL_UNSIGNED_INT`, as even 2 bytes may not be enough for mid-poly and high-poly models.

Comment: Often 16 bit is enough and most engines use that format if possible. You normally have about twice as much triangles as vertices so 16 bit is enough for ~120.000 tris. For one single mesh that's quite a lot.

Answer (score 4):

GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE is 1 byte, GL_SHORT is 2 bytes.  The only advantage of bytes is that they're smaller so they take less memory to store and less time to transfer to the graphics memory (assuming vertex arrays or VBOs).

Beware that not all types are available for all uses:  You can't have GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE vertices, for example.

Answer (score 3):

GPUs only can handle 16 or 32 bit indices, so there is additional overhead when using GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE and no memory saving.