# OpenGL large VBO and VAO

Tags: opengl, vbo, vao

I have issue with drawing big VBO with VAO, because the VBO has more than 65536 vertices and my VAO is just uint, that has maximum 65536.

So my question is, when you have VBO with more than 65536 vertices, how do you draw it? Do you split it into smaller VBO's and then create more VAO's?

Lets say you have terrain of 257x257 vertices, right now I am able draw 256x256 vertices, but I will miss 513 vertices.

Can somebody point me somewhere, where I can learn about this issue?

Than you all.

Comment: You use 4 bytes indices? I'm pretty sure thats doable... [it is](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4215489/583833)

Comment: "*my VAO is just uint, that has maximum 65536.*" ... wat? That doesn't even make sense. A `GLuint` is a 32-bit integer, so it has a higher maximum than that. And the fact that a VAO OpenGL object is stored in a 32-bit integer has *nothing* to do with the size of the vertices it can store.

Comment: Right now, I am using unsigned short[] for storing my indices, i am generating it in DLL module, and it wont let me use bigger value then 65536. 
I am new to OpenGL, so I appreciate every advice.

Comment: @DanielVališ uint ( 4 bytes ) != short ( 2 bytes ). Solution: Use uint in your index buffer instead of a short.If you can't change it from outside i would ask you now if it's possible to call the method differenz times with different parameters, maybe you can later merge the data?

Comment: I changed it right now, and its rlly working.. I dont know why didnt i come up with this solution... Thank you very much guys. 

Just one more question. Is it real to run out from 2^32 indices? Or I should not do such a thing, because it's impposible for HW to draw that much? 

+If you make an answer from comments above, I give you +1.

Comment: @DanielVališ 2^32 indices at 4 bytes each is something like 16GB of RAM in and of itself (excluding the actualy vertex data), you dont need to cover this case in the near future (and by that i mean for at least the next decade)